# MongoDB Aggregation total fields and group by field name

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents like so:

```
{
  gameId: '0001A',
  score: 40,
  name: 'Bob',
  city: 'London'
}
```

I am trying to run an aggregation on my documents that will output the following view FOR EACH `gameId`:

```
{
  cities: [
    London: {
      totalScore: 500 // sum of the scores for all documents that have a city of London
      people: [
        'Bob',
        'Anna',
        'Sally',
        'Sue'
      ],
      peopleCount: 4 // a count of all people who also have the city of London
    },
    Barcelona: {
      totalScore: 400 // sum of the scores for all documents that have a city of Barcelona
      people: [
        'Tim',
        'Tina',
        'Amir'
      ], // names of all people who also have the city of Barcelona
      peopleCount: 3 // count of how many names appear
    },
  ]
```

I've tried to achieve this using `$facet$` and also `$bucket` in the aggregation pipeline. However this doesn't seem to fit the bill, as `$bucket` / `$bucketAuto` seem to require ranges or a number of buckets respectively. The `$bucketAuto` then sets a `min` and `max` value in the objects.

I'm able to group the total number of people, names, and scores straightforwardly like so at the moment:

```
$group: {
  _id: '$gameId',
  totalScore: {
    $sum: '$score'
 },  
  uniqueClients: {
    $addToSet: '$name'
  }
},
$addFields: {
  uniqueClientCount: {
  $size: '$uniqueClients'
 }
}
```

How do I break it down by city?

Answer (score 0):

you could try two `$group` stages as follow :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        game: "$gameId",
        city: "$city"
      },
      "totalScore": {
        "$sum": "$score"
      },
      "people": {
        "$addToSet": "$name"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "peopleCount": {
        "$size": "$people"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.game",
      "cities": {
        "$push": {
          "$arrayToObject": [
            [
              {
                k: "$_id.city",
                v: {
                  people: "$people",
                  totalScore: "$totalScore",
                  peopleCount: "$peopleCount"
                }
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See on mongoplayground https://mongoplayground.net/p/f4uItCb0BwW